# How do I use GETDATE in a WHERE clause using single quotes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I use GETDATE() in a WHERE clause using single quotes? I have the following script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
   pm_requisition.a_requisition
   ,pm_requisition.a_req_description
   ,pm_requisition.rq_position_loc
   ,pm_requisition.rq_status_of_emp
   ,pm_applicant_rec.a_applicant_no
   ,pm_applicant_rec.aq_status_of_appl
   ,pm_applicant_rec.aq_apply_date
FROM
  pm_requisition
  LEFT OUTER JOIN pm_applicant_rec
    ON pm_requisition.a_requisition = pm_applicant_rec.a_requisition
WHERE
  pm_requisition.rq_status_of_req NOT IN (N'6', N'7')
  AND pm_applicant_rec.aq_status_of_appl = N'N'
  AND rq_position_loc = '3300'
  AND pm_applicant_rec.aq_apply_date =  CAST(GETDATE()AS datetime2) --('2021-03-30 00:00:00.000')
```

The dataset does not yield any data using the GETDATE() clause, but if I use today's date (commented out) with single quotes I get the correct dataset. I obviously can't put single quotes around CAST(GETDATE()AS datetime2). Am I missing something simple?

Comment: I am thinking you need to cast to `date` instead of `datetime2`. This is based on my assumption you are not storing the time aspect in `aq_apply_date` or it is also of type `date`.

Comment: whats the data type of aq_apply_date ? aslo provide sample data and desired output

Comment: _Am I missing something simple?_ Yes, because `CAST(GETDATE()AS datetime2) ` simply converts the current date and time returned by GETDATE to a DATETIME2 datatype. It does not (as your comment implies) reset the time portion to the beginning of day.

Comment: If I use GETDATE() only I still do not get a result set. But if I use the just date '2021-03-30' I get the desired output. Here's the result:
2021-03-30 00:00:00.000

Comment: Got it. Had to cast as Date: CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)....it was simple. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), if you combine a `date` and a `datetime2` in an expression, e.g. `=`, then the `date` will be converted to a `datetime2`, not the other way about.

Comment: try this CONVERT(datetime2, GETDATE())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your query does not work is that GETDATE() returns the current date and time, not the current date. As a result, the last line will never match, as you are comparing a date only with a date and time.

Your solution `CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)` works is because it removes the time, which means you are now comparing a date with a date.

If you simplify your SQL to something like this :-

```
SELECT TOP 1 aq_apply_date, 
       GETDATE() [GETDATE]
FROM   pm_applicant_rec;
```

you will see a result like this, so two different values, and clear why they do not match :-

```
aq_apply_date           GETDATE
----------------------- -----------------------
2021-04-04 00:00:00.000 2021-04-04 14:32:15.507
```

*You might see something slightly different depending on the datatype used for aq_apply_date.*